# ¿Las librerias JavaEE se encuentran en el JDK?

Tags: java, java-ee

tengo un codigo JavaEE que me entregaron y estoy intentando hacerlo correr para a partir de alli crear un modulo, entre las varias librerias que se estan importando estan las siguientes:

```
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
```

no me esta reconociendo el paquete javax, y entiendo que ese paquete es netamente JavaEE, no tengo demasiado tiempo trabajando con JavaEE, que sucede ? las apis de JavaEE no vienen en el JDK ? ninguna de esas librerias las reconoce el IDE, estoy usando Eclipse, y tengo el JDK 6 y 7, ya he probado con ambos y no me lo reconoce. Estoy usando el servidor Weblogic 11gR1 y WebLogic 12c para programar.

Comment: Creo que tienes que tomarte la [primera taza de café](https://javaee.github.io/firstcup/toc.html)  es un tutorial completo, sobre cómo se instala y se usa esta tecnología.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respusta corta es que las librerias que necesitas forman parte de tu application server, o servlet containter (Weblogic) en tu caso.

Debes tener una carpeta, probablemnte lib, con los jar.

Debes agregar esos jar a tu class path, pero no exportarlos como parte de tu proyecto.

Answer (score 4):

Java EE refiere a Java Enterprise Edition, que está compuesto por un conjunto de estándares, tal como se indica en la [página oficial de Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html). Para ver las especificaciones que abarca Java EE 8, puedes visitar [este sitio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html)

Cuando se menciona especificación, se puede traducir de manera técnica a un conjunto de interfaces que puedes usar en tu aplicación para obtener una funcionalidad en particular. Algunos ejemplos de las especificaciones que forman parte de Java EE son: Servlets, JSP, JPA, JSF, JAX-WS, JAX-RS, EJB, CDI, JCache, entre otros.

La comunidad provee una implementación de referencia, la cual está compuesta por varios frameworks que proveen una implementación de cada especificación. Por ejemplo, la implementación de referencia actual es [Glassfish 5](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download). Esta implementación es libre y su código fuente lo puedes encontrar en [github](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish). En [este sitio](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/downloads/ri/README) indica los frameworks que usa para su implementación, no directamente, eso se puede revisar en el enlace de la columna RI (reference implementation). Por ejemplo, Java Persistence API aquí se implementa con EclipseLink.

Cabe resaltar que los servidores de aplicaciones implementan una versión específica de Java EE. Por ejemplo, Wildfly 11 soporta/implementa Java EE 7. Es decir, que Wildfly 11 provee implementaciones para Servlets, JSP, JPA, JSF y las demás especificaciones que componen Java EE 7. No significa que deba usar los mismos frameworks/clases de la implementación de referencia, es decir, de Glassfish. Un ejemplo es JPA, que Glassfish lo implementa con EclipseLink (tal como se menciona previamente) mientras que Wildfly usa Hibernate. He aquí que existen diferencias de rendimiento entre servidores de aplicaciones.

---

Con esta base, cabe indicar que si quieres usar los poderes de Java EE, deberás crear un proyecto que se ejecute sobre un servidor de aplicaciones. Para esto, tendrás que descargar un servidor de aplicaciones, a tu preferencia.

Algunos servidores de aplicaciones libres:

- Glassfish
- Wildfly
- TomEE
- Payara

Algunos servidores de aplicaciones pagados:

- Oracle Weblogic
- IBM Websphere Liberty

Comment: Disculpa mi error, no dije el servidor que utilizo, estoy utilizando WebLogic, me gusto tu respuesta, se nota que sabes bien lo que dices, quedo atento a tus comentarios. Gracias!

Comment: En tu IDE, deberás agregar el servidor de aplicaciones que usas. Esto depende mucho del IDE y quizás necesite de algún plugin para poder agregar el servidor específico.